# Normal member methods with same name as templated member methods

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a class which I have called `duo`.

A `duo` is a class which stores an object of any type `T` as well as a `std::string` which is the "text" version of the `T` object. (e.g. if `T` were an `int`, say `861`, then the string version of this would be `"861"`.)

The idea is to have a display string and also a value. I plan on using the `VALUE` for comparisons between two `duo`'s and the `NAME` will be used for a display string when I need one.

It should be able to be constructed from a `std::string` or a `T`. In other words, if I say

```
std::string num("861");
duo<int> anumber(num);
```

that would create the same object as if I did

```
duo<int> anumber(861);
```

Its purpose is to convert and store both so that they can be used later without having to call a conversion function again. I need to be able to access both the "value" and the "name".

If the `duo` is constructed using the "normal version" (passing a `std::string`), `VALUE` will be converted from `name`. If it is constructed using the "templated version" (passing an object of type `T`), `NAME` will be converted from `value`.

```
template< class T >
class duo
{
    private:

        T VALUE;

        std::string NAME;

    public:

        // Templated version
        duo( const T& value );

        // Normal version
        duo( const std::string& name );
};
```

Is there any way `T` can be a `std::string`? How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with an example?

Comment: Why not make one constructor for both? `duo( const std::string& name, const T& value);`

Comment: I edited my question for further clarification, @Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both versions of your constructor but only one class definition which is what I believe after you edit your question you can decide for which parameter type each of your implementations would work with SFINAE.

What is the problem if we write two versions of the constructor as given in the OP question like:

```
duo( const T& value );
duo( const std::string& name );
```

This will fail in the case T is a `std::string` because we now have to times the same signature of the method because the template instantiates to T=std::string so we have two times the signature: `duo( const std::string& name );`

SFINAE enable us to make a template fails to init and so is "invisible" in instantiation. So what we want to achieve:

```
duo( const T& value );
```

This signature should always be taken if parameter of constructor is the same as the class is created for. So if T is int and input parameter is int this version should be taken. This can be achieved with:

```
template <typename X, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,X>::value,
   int>::type* = nullptr >
duo( const X& value ): VALUE(value);
```

But if we have `std::string` as input, we would use a conversion constructor.
But keep in mind, that there is the special case, where T is `std::string` and we do NOT want to use this conversion constructor, because we have no need for conversion! So we also want the above version. So simple use SFINAE to make that version only works if T is NOT `std::string`!

```
template <typename X=T, typename 
    std::enable_if<!std::is_same<X,std::string>::value, int>::type* 
       = nullptr >
duo( const std::string& name );
```

Complete working example with all cases tested:

```
template< class T > 
class duo 
{   
    private:
        T VALUE;
        std::string NAME;

    public:
        // Templated version
        template <typename X, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,X>::value, int>::type* = nullptr >
        duo( const X& value ): VALUE(value)
        {
            std::cout << "Templated version" << std::endl;
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << value << std::endl;

        }

        // Normal version
        // should NOT work if type is std::string, because in this case version above is simplier!
        template <typename X=T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<X,std::string>::value, int>::type* = nullptr >
        duo( const std::string& name )
        {
            std::cout << "Normal version" << std::endl;
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << name << std::endl;

            std::istringstream is(name);
            is >> VALUE;
        }

        T GetVal() 
        {
            return VALUE;
        }
};

int main()
{
    duo<int> int1(1);
    duo<int> int2("123");

    duo<double> double1(1.234);
    duo<double> double2("9.876");

    duo<std::string> string1(std::string("Hallo"));

    std::cout << int1.GetVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << int2.GetVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << double1.GetVal() << std::endl;
    std::cout << double2.GetVal() << std::endl;

    std::cout << string1.GetVal() << std::endl;
}
```

SFINAE works also without c++11 but `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` must be written by your self or simply copied from the STL.

To answer your comment:

If you use a instance of any kind of template, you get a instance of the "thing" which the template describe. A new template instance of your template class will generate new code for that instance. The same for the template constructor. But the overhead is the same as writing the code by hand. And SFINAE generates none overhead! All actions are done during compile time!

Comment: That's interesting... thank you for the answer. Does this add additional overhead? I am trying to keep my classes simple and readable.

Comment: @DustinGoodson: I added some infos to my answer regarding your comment. Also added full working version with example for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, your `main()` looks great, that is exactly how I want to be able to call this class. Give me a while to learn more about this SFINAE, `std::enable_if`, and `std::is_same`, these are new concepts to me. Once I understand I will accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @DustinGoodson: I added some more explanation of usage of SFINAE. Also adapted my example code for using your class with std::string type.

Answer (score 5):

You need the template specialization. See the code below:

```
template< class T >
class duo
{
    private:    
        T VALUE;
        std::string NAME;
    public:
        // Templated version
        duo( const T& value ) : NAME(value), VALUE(value)  // please make sure that NAME(value) works!
        {
            std::cout<<"template version";
        }
};


template<>
class duo<std::string>
{
    private:
        std::string VALUE;
        std::string NAME;
    public:
        // Normal version
        duo( const std::string& name ): NAME(name), VALUE(name)
        {
            std::cout<<"normal version";
        }
};

int main()
{
    duo<std::string> d(std::string("abc"));  // normal version
    // duo<int> d2(1);  // templated version


    return 0;
}
```

`duo<int> d2(1)` doesn't work because `int` can't convert implicitly to `std::string`. This is what you should do next.

Here is the link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

**EDIT**
If you want to specialize the constructor:

```
template< class T >
class duo
{
    private:
        T VALUE;
        std::string NAME;
    public:
        // Templated version
        template<class V>
        duo(const V& value)
        {
            std::cout<<"template version";
        }
        // Normal version
        duo(const std::string &name)
        {
            std::cout<<"normal version";
        }
};
```

Comment: Seems I misunderstood. I thought the goal was to have both methods of construction available for any `T`, not treating `T = std::string` as a special case. What does the OP say?

Comment: @TheVee  Well, as my understanding, I think the OP needs two cases: a template case for all types except `std::string`, the other case for `std::string`.

Comment: There's a conversion function within the constructor that you cannot see... basically it takes either a `std::string` or a `T` and whichever one you don't provide it creates for you using that conversion function. I want the `T` to be used for comparisons or anything needing a true value, and the `std::string` will simply be a display string. In other words, if you create a `duo<int>` you can pass either `4321` or `std::string("4321")` and both will create the exact same object. The conversion function basically just uses a `std::stringstream` to do all of this.

Comment: That is not a solution as I understand the OP because he wants to init a value to the class with a type T or a string not a class for type string.

Comment: @Klaus  Yeah. I misunderstood his question of the first version.

Comment: @Thomas - nice solution (+1) but... why do you use two different (but equals) `std::string` private values in `duo<std::string>` specializarion? Isn't enough a single value?

Comment: @max66  That is the answer for the OP's question of the first version, which you maybe haven't seen.

Comment: @Thomas - sorry but I don't understand; my question is: why do you use `VALUE` and `NAME` in `duo<std::string>`? Isn't enough `template<> class duo<std::string> { private: std::string VALUE; public: duo( const std::string& name ): VALUE(name) { } };`? Or, if you really want both variables, wy not make one a reference to other as in `class duo<std::string> { private: std::string VALUE; std::string & NAME = VALUE; public: duo( const std::string& name ): VALUE(name) { } };` (p.s.: if you declare `VALUE` first and `NAME` second, you should initialize `VALUE` first and `NAME` second).

Comment: @max66  No. Because the OP needs two members there, not me.

Comment: You could also do `template<> duo<std::string>::duo(string const& str) : VALUE(name), NAME(name) {}`

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. If `T` is `std::string` you are defining two constructors of the same signature:

```
duo.cpp:22:20:   required from here
duo.cpp:18:9: error: ‘duo<T>::duo(const string&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ cannot be overloaded
duo.cpp:15:9: error: with ‘duo<T>::duo(const T&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
```

If you want this distinction, one solution is to add a tag parameter to the non-templated version:

```
duo( const std::string& name, bool /* anonymous, not really used */ );
```

If it's considered something of a special case, and you'd like to make it clear you're initializing a different property than using the "normal" constructor, you can also make the constructor private and use a factory method to call it instead:

```
class duo {
    // ...
    public:
        static duo fromName(const std::string& name) {
            return {name, true};
        }
    private:
        duo(const std::string& name, bool);
};
```

Of course, you can do the same with either, or with both constructors. Having a clear semantics is always a good idea, if just constructing the class with one parameter does not have an unambiguous result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, that was the same error I was getting... I don't think I want to have a constructor that requires a second parameter though.

Comment: How about the factory method then? `duo<X> a = duo<X>::fromName(name); duo<Y> b = duo<Y>::fromValue(value)`